# ZF2 - Generating Url from route

Tags: php, url, action, zend-framework2

I can't figure out to generate Url from everywhere i want to, in zend 2

I get action and controller so i try this:

```
$this->url('myControllerName', array('action' => 'myActionName'));
```

But this return an object, i just want the full URL string of this route

Somebody can help me to find the proper way?

EDIT : according to Stoyan, maybe i made a mistake on my route. here is the part of my module.config

```
'router' => array (
                'routes' => array (
                        'indexqvm' => array (
                                'type' => 'segment',
                                'options' => array (
                                        'route' => '/Indexqvm[/:action][/:id_event]',
                                    'constraints' => array (
                                            'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]+',
                                            'id_event' => '[0-9]+'
                                    ),
                                    'defaults' => array (
                                            'controller' => 'Qvm\Controller\Indexqvm',
                                            'action' => 'index' 
                                    ) 
                            ) 
                    ),
```

And my call :

```
echo $this->url('indexqvm', array('action' => 'list-index'));
```

the error : 
    Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url could not be converted to string

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the echo before calling `$this->url(...)` (see bellow) and this will display the whole URL.

```
<?php echo $this->url('route-name', $urlParams, $urlOptions); ?>
```

Note that the first paramter of `url()` is the name of the route as specified in your `[module]/config/module.config.php` file.

See [this](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper) for more information about ZF2's URL view helper.

EDIT in response to the question edit:

The above section is related to using the URL view helper.

If you want a URL in the controller then you need the URL controller plugin.

```
<?php $url = $this->url()->fromRoute('route-name', $params, $options); ?>
```

[This](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-url-plugin) is the reference to the ZF2 manual for this controller plugin.

Hope this helps :)

Stoyan

Comment: Thank you Stoyan for this fast answer, 
however, as i don't get a string, i can't echo it :
Catchable fatal error: Object of class Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Url could not be converted to string
Maybe i made a mistake regarding my routes, i will edit my post to add my code

Comment: @Reign.85 I edited my answer based on your edit. Hope this will give you idea of how to create the url :)

Comment: Tank you so much, this work for me, i just need to add the server url to the path

Answer (score 1):

You can use this in the .phtml file

```
echo $this->url('HelloWorld/default', array('controller'=>'Index', 'action'=>'registration'));
```

Where HelloWorld/default is the routing and the remaining is the controller and its action and also you can send the others parameter adding just in array as key and value pair.