# zf2 $this-url with dynamic routes

Tags: zend-framework2

I have following routes in my module.config.php

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Index',
                        'action'     => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            // The following is a route to simplify getting started creating
            // new controllers and actions without needing to create a new
            // module. Simply drop new controllers in, and you can access them
            // using the path /application/:controller/:action
            'application' => array(
                'type'    => 'Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route'    => '/application',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                        'controller'    => 'Index',
                        'action'        => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
                'may_terminate' => true,
                'child_routes' => array(
                    'default' => array(
                        'type'    => 'Segment',
                        'options' => array(
                            'route'    => '/[:controller[/:action]]',
                            'constraints' => array(
                                'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                                'action'     => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                            ),
                            'defaults' => array(
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

and I have following URLs in my Layout.phtml file.

```
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('home') ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('Home') ?></a></li>
<li class="active"><a href="<?php echo $this->url('application',array('controller'=> 'mycontrollername', 'action'=>'index')) ?>"><?php echo $this->translate('My URL') ?></a></li>
```

Home link is working fine, for second dynamic one, It should look like this. `<a href="/application/mycontrollername/index">My URL</a>`

But instead it is generating this
`<a href="/application">My URL</a>`

Any Idea?

I have checked following links but none of these helped me to sort this problem. I prefer to use URl Helper rather then hard code it.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-url-plugin

[ZF2: Get module name (or route) in the application layout for menu highlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16077159/zf2-get-module-name-or-route-in-the-application-layout-for-menu-highlight)

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.html#url-helper

[ZF2 - Generating Url from route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766231/zf2-generating-url-from-route)

[ZF2 - Get controller name into layout/views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843092/zf2-get-controller-name-into-layout-views)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php echo $this->url ('application/default', array ('controller' => 'xxx', 'action' => 'x')); ?>
```

Comment: What the hell!? Why putting default in front of the module name make it work?

Comment: Oh, now i get it. This is a named route right? I can have many of that with different names that maps to different stuff?